# How to know where in /dev/ is a USB keyboard loaded?

Tags: usb, kernel, keyboard, udev, input-devices

To be precise, when you plug in a USB storage device, it is loaded in `sd` something, but where is a usb keyboard loaded in `/dev/`?

Answer (score 3):

Keyboards use event device files. You can find them in `/dev/input/event*`. To find the exact path you can `egrep -i "keyboard.+\/dev" /var/log/Xorg.0.log`

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a little late to reply but I hope this is helpful for friends.

“mice” contains mouse input data, but to find the file related to the keyboards we need to check the files in folder “by-path”, keyboards file names end with “event-kbd”. We need to find the links to the keyboards, and then we can find the keyboards event file. The following commands can do this automatically for us:

```
kbdEvents=($(ls /dev/input/by-path | grep "event-kbd"))     
for forCounter in "${kbdEvents[@]}"
do
    eventFile=$(readlink --canonicalize "/dev/input/by-path/${forCounter}")     
    # do anything ...
done
```

This code is part of the code for the break time on my personal website : [mazKnez.com](http://mazknez.com/linux-bash-script-to-remind-you-of-the-break-timeresttime/)